# Purging Logs in SQL Database - Serilog

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, serilog

I am using serlog for logging in my webapi and working fine. I used SQL Server to log and the following is the serlog config for the same.

```
        __serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationIPv4", _ipv4)
             .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationIPv6", _ipv6)
              .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, tableName /*, columnOptions: columnOptions*/)
            .WriteTo
            .Seq(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SerilogServer"])
            .CreateLogger();
```

I am beginner in serilog. My confusion is how to purge the logs in database. Any options in serilog to hold last 3 months data only like that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on chat in serilog Gitter, there is no option for that. We can do using Sql Job Agent or any other scheduled job.